# does parent component re-renders when changes occur in child components?

Tags: reactjs, react-component

I have a parent component which looks like this:

```
const Parent = () => {
    return (
       <Child_1 />
       <Child_2 />
   );
}
```

if any changes occur in one of the child components, will the Parent component re-renders ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No, it will not re-render. If you pass any props to the component from the parent component and you update that prop in children or that prop update in the parent component so both will re-render. But if the data or state has no dependency on the parent component so it will not cause a re-render in the parent component.

Answer (score 5):

State changes in Child component doesn't effect on the parent component, but when a state of parent component changes all the child components render.

Answer (score 0):

No, in your case absolutely not. Let's see when the parent re-renders and when not.

## Case 1 : When there is no state transfer from parent to child

```
const Parent = () => {
    return (
       <Child_1 />
       <Child_2 />
   );
}
```

This is your case, where the parent does not transfer any state as prop. In this case the child re-renders independently, not causing the parent to re-render.

## Case 2 : When there is state transfer from parent to child

```
const Child = ({parentState, setParentState}) => {
 return <div onClick={() => setParentState(parentState+1)} >{parentState}</div>
}

const Parent = () => {
 const [parentState, setParentState] = useState(0);
 return <Child parentState={parentState} setParentState={setParentState}>;
};
```

In this case, whenever the user clicks on the div of Child, the state `parentState` changes, leading to re-render in both `Child` and `Parent`.